# How to access subdirectories of a Hidden Directory(.foldername) of a App using Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, file

I am Creating a Flutter app that requires to access a hidden folder in  a App Directory
I am using-

> `Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Android/$path');`

to get the access of the sub directories
But the sub directories of (.folderName) are not showing

Comment: I dont see a .folderName.